# LIBGDX Box2D Lights on Ios-Moe

Tags: ios, libgdx, crash, lighting, box2dlights

My question is self explainatory: is it possible to use Box2D and Box2D lights on a ios-moe build of LIBGDX? I can run it on my desktop but I get the following error when I launch on IOS:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(float, float, boolean) (tried
```

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
project(":ios-moe") {
apply plugin: "moe"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-moe:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

}
project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace the content of `/Applications/Intel/multi_os_engine/tools/proguard.cfg` with  `/Applications/Intel/multi_os_engine/tools/proguard-full.cfg`

Comment: Where would this directory be? I'm on a mac and can't find my Intel folder.

Comment: Also, I've investigated more. The physics library isn't loaded because the UnsatisfiedLinkError means it could not match the method. The project runs on Xcode fine and the library is loaded with gradle, it has also been cleaned and re-built. For the life of me I can't figure this out!

Comment: It points to where I create a new World() as the problem which means it is because the library isn't loaded. I've tried to load it statically with Box2D.init() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `/Users/user-name/.moe/moe-sdk-1.4.2/tools/proguard.cfg`

Comment: Replaced those files. Same outcome. Whatever I do, ios-moe won't load the physics library even though it is properly in the path.

Comment: @Aryan I replaced the files and still the same outcome, how ever Tom Ski (from LibGDX) says it is a problem with that file. Is there another way? How can I make sure my IOS module is using the 1.4.0 version (my latest installed version) of MOE?